# how to import avro file in ADLS in Azure Analysis Service model?

Tags: avro, azure-data-lake, azure-analysis-services

After the support of ADLS as back end in Azure Analysis service , we want to import avro file from ADLS into Azure Analysis service  .

The file size will be in range of TBs ( 2-4 ) .

Azure online documentation tells about csv only and not of avro . Is it possible to import avro from ADLS ( azure data lake store ) into Azure Analysis service ?